# query snowflake s3 external file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've created an S3 [external] stage and uploaded csv files into \stage*.csv folder.
I can see stage content by doing list @my_stage.

if I query the stage
select $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6 from @my_s3_stage it looks like I'm randomly picking up files.

So I'm trying to select from specific file by adding a pattern
PATTERN => job.csv

This returns no results.

Note: I've used snowflake for all of 5 hours so pretty new to syntax

Comment: add the entire stage and file name select $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6 from @my_s3_stage/job.csv.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a pattern you can use

```
select t.$1, t.$2 from @mystage1 (file_format => 'myformat', pattern=>'.*data.*[.]csv.gz') t;
```

The pattern is a regex expression.
For a certain file you have to add the file name to the query like this:

```
select t.$1, t.$2 from @mystage/data1.csv.gz;
```

If your file format is set in your stage definition, you don't need the file format-parameter.

More info can be found here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage.html

Comment: I'm assuming I don't need to specify the \stage in my query because I included it the stage definition URL ? i.e. create stage.... url = 's3://testbucket/stage'. What is the general approach on naming for buckets ?